# How to integrate qtest with java selenium

Tags: java

Integrate Test with java. I am able to create test run under root, but not able to create a test run under a specific test cycle.

Here is the code which I used:

```
 TestExecutionService testExecutionService = new TestExecutionServiceClient(credentials, config);
 TestDesignService testDesignService = new TestDesignServiceClient(credentials, config);

 TestCycle cycleId =testExecutionService.createTestCycle(new CreateTestCycleRequest()
                        .withProjectId(projectId)
                        .withTestCycle(new TestCycle().withName("Sisir cycle test"))
                        );

 TestCase testcase = testDesignService.getTestCase(new GetTestCaseRequest().withProjectId(projectId).withTestCaseId(146983L));

 TestRun   testRun = testExecutionService.createTestRun(new CreateTestRunRequest()
                             .withProjectId(projectId)
                             .withTestRun(new TestRun().withTestCase(testcase)
                             .withName("Thank u")));
```

I am able to create a Testrun under a project. But how can I create a testrun under a specific test cycle. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post the code you're using to create a test run.

Comment: i have updated the code.Could you please help.